# Combining CSV Files with different column data on one column

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

A sample dataset is structured as follows

- Home_HeatSensor_AA.CSV
- Office_HeatSensor_BB.CSV
- Ship_ElevationSensor_XXYY.CSV

AA.CSV has the following columns, with a sample row

```
   Time  AA  AB  BB  Site  Type
0  1:00   5   4   5  Home  Heat
```

BB.CSV is formatted similarly

```
   Time  AA  AB  BB    Site  Type
0  1:00   6   2   4  Office  Heat
```

However, XXYY.CSV has a much different format

```
   Time     XX       XY     YY  Site       Type
0  1:00  1.332  12.1123  4.212  Ship  Elevation
```

I need to join these three CSV files into a master CSV file formatted as follows

```
   Time AA AB AB     XX       XY     YY    Site       Type
0  1:00  5  4  4                           Home       Heat
0  1:00  6  2  2                         Office       Heat
0  1:00           1.332  12.1123  4.212    Ship  Elevation
```

I've tried mucking about with pandas a bit but the results have been mixed. The code below will join the data but switches but the column order of time, Site, and Unit. Ideally I'd like these two to stay static, with time in the front of the order and Site and Unit staying the last two column values

```
for filename in filepaths:
 df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=None, header=0, parse_dates=True,infer_datetime_format=True)
 li.append(df)
```

Answer (score 2):

#### `pd.concat`

```
def read_csv(fn):
    return pd.read_csv(fn, skipinitialspace=True)

files = ['Home_HeatSensor_AA.CSV', 'BB.CSV', 'XXYY.CSV']
cols = ['Time', 'AA', 'AB', 'BB', 'XX', 'XY', 'YY', 'Site', 'Type']

pd.concat(map(read_csv, files), sort=False)[cols].to_csv('MASTER.CSV', index=False)
```

Then confirm

```
cat MASTER.CSV

Time,AA,AB,BB,XX,XY,YY,Site,Type
1:00,5.0,4.0,5.0,,,,Home,Heat
1:00,6.0,2.0,4.0,,,,Office,Heat
1:00,,,,1.3319999999999999,12.1123,4.212,Ship,Elevation
```

---

If you won't know the column names in advanced:

```
def read_csv(fn):
    return pd.read_csv(fn, skipinitialspace=True)

files = ['Home_HeatSensor_AA.CSV', 'BB.CSV', 'XXYY.CSV']

pd.concat(map(read_csv, files), sort=False).to_csv('MASTER.CSV', index=False)
```

Comment: Its a good answer, but I won't know the column names in advance. Users could upload a new file with a new set of column names, and the code needs to account for that

Comment: Without the column names, pandas places the columns in some order. I used the column names to present the result in the order you specified.  If you won't know the column names, leave it out.